# Modify Stored procedure parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

My Stored procedure takes one parameter @IDs and it has values in it like '1,2,3'. I want to get rid of these single quotes. How can I do it? Like I want just 1,2,3 and NOT '1,2,3'. How do I modify this parameter value inside my SP?

Comment: you mean your procedure takes an array of ids

Comment: I think the OP means that the procedure currently takes a single string variable. What's being passed to it is a string containing a comma-delimited set of values. Inside of the sproc they'd like this converted to some form of array or table so they can access these values individually. @Serenity, is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

you can do this:

```
@IDs = REPLACE(@IDs, '''', '');
```

If your parameter is VARCHAR, NVARCHAR or something like string :)

Comment: this would be the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table varaible instead, read in BOoks online for how to do that.